# Does the vector.resize() method calls the default elements constructors when resizing?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am trying the following code:

```
struct _Struct2
{
    void   *ptr;
    double dval;
};

struct _Struct
{
    float fval;
    int   ival;
    std::vector<_Struct2>   data;
};

std::vector<_Struct>    vec;

int main()
{
    vec.resize( 9 );
    for ( int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ )
    {
        _Struct &elem = vec[i];
        int     len = elem.data.size(); // elem.data is [0]()
    }
}
```

The `resize(9)` should allocate 9 elements of type `_Struct` and it works. But every element of type `_Struct` is not initialized, especially the `data` element which is another `std::vector`. I would like it to be initialized to the empty `std::vector`. Do I have to do that manually? I thought that the `resize()` method would have called the default constructor of every `_Struct` element. Thx

Ps. The names of the structs used here are just the first things that come to my mind. This is just an example. My Visual Studio tells me that `elem.data` corresponds in the debug view to `[0]()`.

Ps. Forget the `[0]()`.

Comment: Identifiers that start with an underscore followed by uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: I can't imagine `len = elem.data.size()` not crashing if somehow `data` were not initialized (which it should definitely be). What is exactly in `data` and what do you expect to be in there?

Comment: Elements in the vector are default constructed upon a `resize` (for an integer this results in 0) For your custom class, You should define your own default constructor.

Comment: and calling a struct Struct is a bad idea anyway

Comment: `data` should be initalized to an empty vector. Isn't it? If not what *is* it initalized to?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: That's true, but as a practical matter it should not have made a difference as regards the OP's question. In other words, I don't think that fixing that will make the problem (whatever that is) go away.

Comment: @Jon: I didn't say otherwise. It's a comment, not an answer, for a reason.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Sure. It's simply that IMHO it would have been an even better comment with an *(although this will not fix your particular problem)* or similar at the end.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No it doesn't call default element constructor. `std::vector` never calls default constructors internally (it does in C++11, but not in earlier versions of the specification).

The full signature for `vector::resize` looks as follows

```
void resize(size_type sz, T c = T());
```

I.e. it has a second parameter (with default argument value). That second parameter is then used as a "source" object to initialize new elements by *copy-constructor*.

In other words, your call to `resize` is actually equivalent to

```
vec.resize( 9, _Struct() );
```

meaning that it is *you* who called the default constructor when you supplied that "source" object to `vector::resize`, even though you didn't notice that.

> But every element of type _Struct is not initialized, especially the
>   data element, which is another std::vector.

Huh? "Not initialized"? I don't know what that is supposed to mean, considering that in your sample code every new element created by `resize` is perfectly initialized as described above: it is copy-initialized from a `_Struct()` element you implicitly supplied to `resize` as the second argument. Each `_Struct::fval` and `_Struct::ival` is zero, and each `_Struct::data` is an empty vector.

(In the original C++98 `_Struct::fval` and `_Struct::ival` will remain uninitialized, since pre-TC1 C++98 didn't support *value-initialization*. But `_Struct::data` will be initialized to an empty vector even in the original C++98).

> I would like it to be initialized to the empty std::vector.

Every `_Struct::data` vector is already initialized as an empty vector. What made you believe that it isn't?

P.S. Names that begin with `_` followed by an uppercase letter are reserved by the implementation. You are not allowed to use them.

Comment: Does C++11 add an emplacing version of `resize`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I don't see an emplacing version there, but C++11 does split `vector::resize` into two functions: 1) just size and 2) size and "source" object. The first version now performs value-initialization internally, meaning that my answer is not fully accurate for C++11 (even though the final result is the same)

Comment: @KerrekSB I think it's possible to be done in two steps: `reserve(myWantedSize)` and then perform for-loop iterating `myWantedSize` times. On every iteration call `.emplaceBack(myArg1, myArg2, myArg3, etc)`